# Children's book of true ghost stories from the 1980/90s

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, childrens-novel

I looked through other questions but couldn't see anything like what I'm looking for.

I checked out a collection of ghost stories every year from my elementary school library, so from about 1993-2000. The book was a paperback chapter book and I think had a dark blue cover. It included several true ghost stories and there were no illustrations.

I distinctly remember a chapter about the Bell Witch of Tennessee, and other chapters included ghost ships or pirates and maybe the Bermuda triangle? All stories were meant to be true; each chapter would include what had happened, like who had died or disappeared, and then any paranormal things after that, like people seeing the same ship after too many years, or something like that. I mainly remember it being American-centric.

Comment: So, just to clarify, not all of them were meant to be true stories?

Comment: Hi there! :) you might want to take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in your question. For instance, did you read that in English? Was it a translation? The two examples you provided sound very "American" - were there European/Asian/African/Oceanian stories as well? Things like that, to incease the chances of a successful ID. Cheers!

Comment: Technically, if they were all alleged true, this would be off-topic for our site (this would be an historical work, rather than SF or fantasy). *Technically*. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Can it be Roald Dahl's Book of Ghost Stories? [image: book of ghost stories cover]

Roald Dahl searched through various sources to find the bests ghost stories and made a book of short stories. There were a ghost ship and was released in 1983.

Comment: No, that's definitely not it. To my knowledge the author wasn't well-known, and it doesn't look like this collection includes the Bell witch.